# Custom Page inside Module

Tags: 7, hooks

I'm trying to embed custom content (custom javascript, paragraphs etc) with a Drupal Form. I'm wondering whats the best way to do it in module?

Something like this:

```
function wow_page() {
    drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });', 'inline'); 
    $output = 'teasdasdst';
    $output = '<div id="test"></div>';
    $output .= drupal_get_form('wow_cake');
    return array('#markup' => $output);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. What exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps give an example of a use case?

Answer (score 0):

ok add hook_menu that call this function

if you have module called wow

```
function wow_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['home'] = array(
    'title' => '',
    'page callback' => 'wow_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  ); 
  return $items;
}
```

Comment: I already did that, it's all working but my question is really how to construct the page function so it can output multiple things easily.

Comment: what do you mean output multiple things you display html that can be whatever u want or you can use hook_theme to make a new tpl page